# How to squash commits in git after they have been pushed?

Tags: git, squash

This gives a good explanation of squashing multiple commits:

http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Rebasing

but it does not work for commits that have already been pushed. How do I squash the most recent few commits both in my local and remote repos?

When I do `git rebase -i origin/master~4 master`, keep the first one as `pick`, set the other three as `squash`, and then exit (via c-x c-c in emacs), I get:

```
$ git rebase -i origin/master~4 master
# Not currently on any branch.
nothing to commit (working directory clean)

Could not apply 2f40e2c... Revert "issue 4427: bpf device permission change option added"
$ git rebase -i origin/master~4 master
Interactive rebase already started
```

where 2f40 is the `pick` commit. And now none of the 4 commits appear in `git log`. I expected my editor to be restarted so that I could enter a commit message. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not that comprehensive, but easy to read: https://www.internalpointers.com/post/squash-commits-into-one-git

Answer (score 1150, accepted):

Squash commits locally with:

```
git rebase -i origin/master~4 master
```

where `~4` means the last 4 commits.

This will open your default editor. Here, replace `pick` in the second, third, and fourth lines (since you are interested in the last 4 commits) with `squash`. The first line (which corresponds to the newest commit) should be left with `pick`. Save this file.

Afterwards, your editor will open again, showing the messages of each commit. Comment the ones you are not interested in (in other words, leave the commit message that will correspond to this squashing uncommented). Save the file and close it.

You will than need to push again with the -f flag.

and then force push with :

```
git push origin +master
```

---

#### Difference between `--force` and `+`

From the documentation of [`git push`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#Documentation/git-push.txt---force):

> Note that `--force` applies to all the refs that are pushed, hence using
> it with `push.default` set to `matching` or with multiple push
> destinations configured with `remote.*.push` may overwrite refs other
> than the current branch (including local refs that are strictly behind
> their remote counterpart). To force a push to only one branch, use a `+`
> in front of the refspec to push (e.g `git push origin +master` to force
> a push to the `master` branch).

Comment: you can also `git push --force origin master`

Comment: _[Daenyth](http://stackoverflow.com/users/350351/daenyth)_: Yes, but I always prefer this syntax as this is shorter.

Comment: And of course, realize that if anyone else might've pulled from the remote repository, you probably don't want to do this - the answer in that case is "you don't."

Comment: Also, I think the OP is exactly copying the command `git rebase -i origin/master`, and actually wants to know how to rebase commits farther back than that, e.g. `git rebase -i origin/master~20 master`.

Comment: @Jefromi: Why? What will happen in that case? Please explain for someone like me who haven't tried doing that.

Comment: @HelloGoodbye Because then the history they have will conflict with the rewritten history you've just pushed, and it can be a huge pain to sort everyone out. See for example https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rebase.html#_recovering_from_upstream_rebase, or one of the zillions of questions here about it.

Comment: @Jefromi: But as long as you're sure no one has pulled from the remote repository you're fine? For example if you are the only person who has read access to the remote repository and you haven't pulled from it in any other local repository you might have.

Comment: @HelloGoodbye Yes, my comment did say *if anyone else might've pulled from the remote repository*.

Comment: For public git service, it is quite likely that you encountered `denying non-fast-forward`, please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22026489/git-puzzler-working-around-denying-non-fast-forward for solution

Comment: Does "+" equal "--force"?

Comment: *[gstackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2674303/gstackoverflow)*: `+` forces only the refspec which is prefixed by it. `--force` will force all the refspecs being pushed. Please see the updated answer.

Comment: How does one locally squash commits after having pushed them? Whenever I try to do that, I simply get "noop" in the editor.

Comment: I think I just figured it out....I needed to set the upstream a few commits back.

Comment: @Jefromi You are correct about being careful with rewriting history on remote branches. But there are also cases when it's a good idea. For instance, I maintain several private repositories for open source projects. I test them on different machines so I push partially completed branches back to my remote all the time. When the time comes to make a pull request, I squash all commits which creates this very situation. And this is the preferred method of contributing to open source projects. But as you mention, the key is knowing that no one else is forking my private branch.

Comment: Does this actually work as intended? I could see the `git log` indicating commits are squashed successfully on my local, but on another clone, say, on another developer's PC (and in Atlassian BitBucket Server, of course), it lists the original unsquashed commits and then the squashed commit. What's the point of squashing then?! Does the version of the `git` matter? (I hope not.)

Comment: Nice method :) You can also force push (if really needed) with `git push --force-with-lease` to do a  "smooth force". Found it here : https://developer.atlassian.com/blog/2015/04/force-with-lease/

Comment: It fails for me.  I do the first command  - "git rebase -i origin/master~20 master".  This gives me a vi window and I change all the 'pick' lines to 'squash' and get the error message "cannot 'squash' without a previous commit.

Comment: @SteveCohen You have to leave one of the commits as 'pick': the rebase is squashing the 'squash' ones into the commit of the 'pick' one (presumably the first 'pick' one before if you leave more than one as 'pick').

Comment: If you are squashing all the way back to the root commit you need to use `git rebase -i --root` otherwise it will fail with `fatal: Needed a single revision`

Comment: Notice: you should change to `squash` all the entries for the commits that you want to squash, and `pick` for the ones you want to pick. And the commits appear in reversed order (newer on top). (See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39595034/git-cannot-squash-without-a-previous-commit-error-while-rebase)

Comment: local squash and then force push works flawlessly!

Comment: and also you most likely need to a force pull in another local machine using `git reset --hard origin/<branch-name>`

Comment: To quit the console, press ```ESC``` and type ```:wq!```

Comment: And then, when you are in the VIM editor, press ```ESC``` and type ```ZZ``` (uppercase) to close it.

Comment: I do `git rebase -i origin/master~2 master`, expecting it to pick up the last two commits, but it picks up the last three commits.  I don't understand why.

Answer (score 304):

On a branch I was able to do it like this (for the last 4 commits)

```
git checkout my_branch
git reset --soft HEAD~4
git commit
git push --force origin my_branch
```

Comment: Doing this with the soft command on an already pushed branch ended up pushing a ton of other peoples commits for me.

Comment: A ton? How can it be more than 4? Can you elaborate?

Comment: That I am unsure of but it had something to do with trying to squash an already pushed commit.  Looks like others experienced similar here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189560/squash-my-last-x-commits-together-using-git#comment52575762_5201642

Comment: I would have accepted this as expected answer. More cleaner that accepted answer.

Comment: This is the most clear and accepted answer in just 4 steps

Comment: very short and simple, instead of going through resolving conflicts and getting yourself into creating a branch with detached HEAD and evrything.

Comment: this is what i use because i get stuck with interactive rebasing, because after rewinding and amending the commit, git will say its current position is at [ <someHash> | REBASE-i ] and i dont know how to continue from there because none of the internet guides ive looked at include this part

Comment: How does this squash commits, this will remove the last 4 commits completely? This will annihilate your branch.

Comment: This is a very wrong answer. This will cause a lot of complications if you work with others.

Comment: @tuemar29 Changing anything in the log (ie using a force push) will cause complications when working with others.

Comment: This answer is clear and working well for me.

Comment: @tuemar29 when you work on your own feature branch, you are the one who edit it, so there would not be any complications.

Answer (score 130):

Minor difference to accepted answer, but I was having a lot of difficulty squashing and finally got it.

```
$ git rebase -i HEAD~4
```

- At the interactive screen that opens up, replace *pick* with *squash*
  at the top for all the commits that you want to squash.
- Save and close the editor

Push to the remote using:

```
$ git push origin branch-name --force
```

Comment: brief and effective, elaborate:

Comment: esc --> :wq provided that the editor is the vi or vim

Comment: Correct and precise. The force push is important to do. Do not pull before pushing.

Comment: Thanks for that! Just a note for others, I used `+branch-name` instead of `branch-name --force`, as suggested in another answer - should be safer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/5668050/997940)

Answer (score 38):

`git rebase -i master`

you will get the editor vm open and msgs something like this

```
Pick 2994283490 commit msg1
f 7994283490 commit msg2
f 4654283490 commit msg3
f 5694283490 commit msg4
#Some message 
#
#some more
```

Here I have changed pick for all the other commits to "f" (Stands for fixup).

`git push -f origin feature/feature-branch-name-xyz`

this will fixup all the commits to one commit and will remove all the other commits .
I did this and it helped me.

Comment: This needs to be the top answer and thank you. I find this answer a better way of squashing than blindly doing it based on number of commits . Especially with the VM editor you can do lot of things at once like changing the commit, removing commit and of course squashing.

Answer (score 35):

A lot of problems can be avoided by only creating a `branch` to work on & **not** working on `master`:

`git checkout -b mybranch`

The following works for `remote` commits already pushed & a mixture of `remote` pushed commits / `local` only commits:

```
# example merging 4 commits

git checkout mybranch
git rebase -i mybranch~4 mybranch

# at the interactive screen
# choose fixup for commit: 2 / 3 / 4

git push -u origin +mybranch
```

I also have some [pull request notes](https://it-offshore.co.uk/code/81-alpine-linux-pull-requests-on-github) which may be helpful.

Answer (score 16):

1)  `git rebase -i HEAD~4`

To elaborate: It works on the current branch; the HEAD~4 means squashing the latest four commits; interactive mode (-i)

2)  At this point, the editor opened, with the list of commits, to change the second and following commits, replacing pick with squash then save it.

output: Successfully rebased and updated refs/heads/branch-name.

3)  `git push origin refs/heads/branch-name --force`

output:

```sh
remote:
remote: To create a merge request for branch-name, visit:
remote: http://xxx/sc/server/merge_requests/new?merge_request%5Bsource_branch%5D=sss
remote:To ip:sc/server.git
 + 84b4b60...5045693 branch-name -> branch-name (forced update)
```

Answer (score 13):

Sqush Changes in remote

- First ensure your local master is at par with remote
- Then reset your local feature branch to be at par with master: `git reset --soft master`
- then add all your modifications and changes (that you made on your
  local feature branch you just reset to master) to staging area:  `git add .`
- then commit these changes:   `git commit -m "this is the final commit message"`
- then force push to remote branch:    `git push RemoteBranch --force`

Answer (score 7):

For squashing two commits, one of which was already pushed, on a single branch the following worked:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~2
    [ pick     older-commit  ]
    [ squash   newest-commit ]
git push --force
```

By default, this will include the commit message of the newest commit as a comment on the older commit.

Answer (score 7):

When you are working with a Gitlab or Github you can run in trouble in this way. You squash your commits with one of the above method. My preferite one is:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~4
or
git rebase -i origin/master
```

select squash or fixup for yours commit. At this point you would check with git status. And the message could be:

```
    On branch ABC-1916-remote
    Your branch and 'origin/ABC-1916' have diverged,
    and have 1 and 7 different commits each, respectively.
      (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)
```

And you can be tempted to pull it. **DO NOT DO THAT** or you will be in the same situation as before.

Instead push to your origin with:

```
git push origin +ABC-1916-remote:ABC-1916
```

The + allow to force push only to one branch.

Comment: there's nothing wrong on pulling, specially if you have conflicts they can be resolved easier than if you force push

Comment: @Ray_Poly - won't that just put those remote commits back as local commits?  That's what I've found.

Comment: yes, it'll create a new commit, but you can see in that commit the differences, better than re-writing the git history everytime you rebase

Answer (score 2):

For whom might be interested, this is how it looks like when you squash commits in GitHub PR.

**Before:**
[image]

**After:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In my case requirement was to squash all the feature branch commits into one, to have a clean commit history. Utilized the GitHub UI to do so.

Problem:

- Feature branch (eg:featureBranch) has been created from master (a month ago).
- Committed all my changes to the featureBranch (~12 commits, a month of work). And has been pushed to remote regularly.

Requirement:

- To Get the feature branch updated with the master and to have a single commit   in a featureBranch

Steps followed:

- Create a new branch (eg: featureBranchLatest) from master in GitHub UI.
- Create a PR from featureBranch to featureBranchLatest.
- Resolve conflicts if any. Merge the PR with the squash commit option in GitHub UI. (Alter the commit message to have a cleaner message).

Now the featureBranchLatest will have a single commit of all the changes needed in a single commit, along with the latest changes from the master. Delete the old branch featureBranch if not required for reference.

Answer (score 0):

## Merge (rebase) commits in a specifc branch

### List all specifc branch commits

**MODEL**

```
git cherry -v <ORIGINAL_BRANCH> <YOUR_BRANCH>
```

**EXAMPLE**

```
git cherry -v main some_branch_name
```

[Ref(s).: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24668421/3223785 ]

If there is more than one commit in the created branch, perform a rebase to centralize everything in just one commit.

**TIP:** This process is important for organizing and ensuring that all changes made in one branch can be brought over to another branch in a cherry pick process if this is the scenario.

### Merge (rebase) commits

The rebase is basically a "merge" of commits.

**MODEL**

```
git rebase -i origin/<YOUR_BRANCH>~<NUMBER_COMMITS_TO_REBASE> <YOUR_BRANCH>
```

**EXAMPLE**

```
git rebase -i origin/some_branch_name~2 some_branch_name
```

**NOTE:** The *<NUMBER_COMMITS_TO_REBASE>* means the number of commits you are going to merge (rebase) - that is, the number of commits displayed by the "List all specifc branch commits" command - and `-i` means interactive mode.

A text editor will open. Keep only the commits (hash) shown by the "List all branch commit..." command. Keep the oldest commit (it will appear first) as "pick" and the others in sequence change to "squash". This configuration file after being saved will be executed as a batch by git.

**MODEL**

```
git push origin +<YOUR_BRANCH>
```

**EXAMPLE**

```
git push origin +some_branch_name
```

**IMPORTANT:** To force a push TO ONLY ONE BRANCH (*<YOUR_BRANCH>*), use a `+` in front of it to push.

[Ref(s).: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5668050/3223785 ]

Answer (score 0):

Many of the proposed solutions require doing a `git push --force` at the end. In my case, the git repository was configured to disallow `git push --force`, so I was stuck.

Here's how I went about squashing my commits on the `feature-branch`:

1. Switch to main: `git switch main`
2. Create a new branch from main: `git switch -c feature-branch-2`
3. Cherry-pick every commit from feature-branch that you want to squash (without committing): `git cherry-pick -n <hash>`
4. Commit all the changes (cherry-pick -n has automatically staged them): `git commit -m "New message"`
5. Push the new branch: `git push origin -u feature-branch-2`
6. Delete your old local branch: `git branch -D feature-branch`

If you have the necessary permissions, you can also delete the old remote branch. Otherwise, you can ask someone with the appropriate permissions to do it, or simply wait for it to become stale.