# How to squash and rebase already pushed branch into master?

Tags: git

I have a branch *x* that was **already pushed** because there are more of us working on that feature. Now I would like to to **rebase it** on top of master and **squash** some commits.

My current workflow is:

```
git co x
git format-patch HEAD~28
git co master
git am 00*.patch
git rebase -i HEAD~28
git push
git push origin :x
```

I am pretty sure is much better workflow available. Because it is a git. Help, thanks.

Okay I **found a solution** using cherry-pick with a range:

```
git cherry-pick XXX..YYY
```

Feel free to add additional solutions, will upvote them all when appropriate ;-)

Comment: Maybe it can helps you ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5667884/how-to-squash-commits-in-git-after-they-have-been-pushed

Comment: Well, I dont want to force pushing it. I want to put it on top of my master branch and then delete the "x" branch. But thanks!

Comment: Can you please spell out the `...`s? I suspect the 4 commands (format-patch_co+am+rebase) can be done with just one rebase or merge with appropriate arguments, but I can't tell for sure without those arguments.

Comment: +Jan Hudec - edited. Those are pseudo commands, but it should work I hope. Thanks!

Comment: Got an idea of something like: git rebase --onto a b f

Comment: Git cherry-pick B..A worked! Then I did rebase. Okay. Solved.

Comment: Note that rebasing stuff that has been shared is often frowned upon, since you are rewriting history that others have based their commits on.