# Git puzzler - Working around `denying non-fast-forward`

Tags: git, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

In my local git repository, I had essentially:

```
* commit A
|
* commit B (master) (origin/master)
```

I made some changes so it is now:

```
* commit A
|\
| * commit B (develop) (origin/master)
|
* commit C (master)
```

I would like the Git repo (hosted on beanstalkapp.com) to be updated to reflect this, and look like:

```
* commit A
|\
| * commit B (develop) (origin/develop)
|
* commit C (master) (origin/master)
```

How can I do this? `git push` fails with `denying non-fast-forward refs/head/master`. What are my options to work around this?

My repo hasn't been very organized, and I'd like to refactor it once and for all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
git checkout master
git merge origin/master strategy=ours
git push origin master
```

The 'ours' strategy ignores all changes made between commit `A` and `B`, and makes a "fake" merge (a merge in name only). `git push` then happily does a fast-forward commit between the old `origin/master` and the new `master`.

The result:

```
* commit A
|\
| * commit B (develop)
| |
* | commit C
| /
* commit D, but identical to C (master) (origin/master)
```

Comment: Can we apply this to branches as well? Also between the checkout and merge you did your changes then it seems?

Comment: @pal4life Yes. master is an ordinary branch like any other. Not sure of your second question.

Answer (score 2):

Are you allowed to do a forced push?

Otherwise are you allowed to delete a branch? In that case you can just delete the old branch and push the new one, which is essentially the same as a forced push.

Comment: Beanstalk doesn't allow forcing push, and I can't delete a branch that hasn't been merged. What I need to do, I think, is to merge `origin/master` into the new `master`, but in a way that keeps the new `master` unmodified (ie, dropping all changes between commit A and B -- a kind of fake merge).

Comment: Seems like beanstalk really wants to keep you from tasks like that. (after all you are really trying to change published history...) If you are sure you want to do it, you might delete you whole repository and recreate it with the new content. - Alternatively just use `git revert` to "undo" your changes. This does leave some superfluous commits, but you can at least create the correct branch content without changing history.