# Detailed reason why remote git rebase is so evil

Tags: git, git-rebase

So I come from a centralized VCS background and am trying to nail down our workflow in Git (new company, young code base). One question I can't find a simple yet detailed answer to is what exactly does rebase on a remote branch do. I understand it rewrites the history, and in general should be limited to local branches only.

The workflow I'm currently trying to vet out involves a remote collaboration branch, each dev "owning" one for the purpose of sharing code. (Having 2 developers and max 3 in the foreseeable future a feature branch for each project & feature request seems excessive and more overhead than benefit gained.)

Then I came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5668050/295686) and tried it and it accomplished what I'd like - a dev commits and pushes often to his own collab branch, when he knows what is approved to be released to staging he can rebase remotely (to squash and perhaps reorganize) before merging into develop.

Enter the original question - if the remote branch is for the purpose of collaboration someone else is bound to pull it sooner or later. If it is a process/training issue to not have the 'guest developer' commit to that collab branch, what actually happens with the branch owner rebases that remote branch?

Comment: One key to understanding this in Git is that in Git, branch *names* are almost irrelevant. What matters is raw commit hash IDs. Rebase works by *copying* existing commits to new commits. If there is even a single bit changed in the copy, the new commit has a new, different ID. Branch *structures* are formed by commit IDs. Everything else is simply a consequence of these two basic facts (plus the idea that fetch and push *use* names to transfer IDs).

Comment: The other key to understanding this is that the idea of a "remote branch" is essentially just a polite fiction. Your Git repository is *yours*. When you use `git fetch` you collect some name/ID pairs from someone else, and *your* Git *renames* those names and adds/updates IDs as a "remote branch" in *your* repository. There's nothing *remote* about this once `fetch` finishes: it's just your Git remembering "last time I talked to them, they said `master` was `1234567...`.

Comment: Now put those two together: you talk to some remote and it says `branch = 1234567...`. Then they (whoever owns the remote) rebase. Now you talk to them and they say `branch = abcdef0...`. It's now up to you to figure out, somehow, what happened. If everyone agrees in advance that "rebases happen", you can probably figure out what happened. If not—if you're expecting "no rebase ever happens"—you'll get quite confused.

Comment: @torek This was a key piece in helping me understand git branching. Can you convert it to an answer?

Comment: I'll take a stab at it...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's not really *evil*, it's a matter of implementations and expectations.

We start with a tangle of facts:

- Every Git hash represents some unique object.  For our purposes here we need only consider *commit* objects.  Each hash is the result of applying a cryptographic hash function (for Git, specifically, it's SHA-1) to the contents of the object.  For a commit, the contents include the ID of the source tree; the name and email address and time/date-stamp of the author and committer; the commit message; and most crucially here, the ID of the *parent* commit.
- Changing even just a single bit in the content results in a new, very-different hash ID.  The cryptographic properties of the hash function, which serve to authenticate and verify each commit (or other object), also mean that there is no way to have some *different* object have the same hash ID.  Git counts on this for transferring objects between repositories, too.
- Rebase works (necessarily) by copying commits to new commits.  Even if nothing else changes—and usually, the source code associated with the new copies differs from the original source code—the whole *point* of the rebase is to re-parent some commit chain.  For instance, we might start with:

  ```
  ...--o--*--o--o--o   <-- develop
           \
            o--o       <-- feature
  ```

  where branch `feature` separates from branch `develop` at commit `*`, but now we would like `feature` to descend from the tip commit of `develop`, so we rebase it.  The result is:

  ```
  ...--o--*--o--o--o        <-- develop
           \        \
            \        @--@   <-- feature
             \
              o--o          abandoned [used to be feature, now left-overs]
  ```

  where the two `@`s are copies of the original two commits.
- Branch *names*, like `develop`, are just pointers pointing to a (single) commit.  The things we tend think of as "a branch", like the two commits `@--@`, are formed by working backwards from each commit to its parent(s).
- Branches are always expected to grow new commits.  It's perfectly normal to find that `develop` or `master` has some new commits added on, so that the name now points to a commit—or the last of many commits—that points back to where the name *used* to point.
- Whenever you get *your* Git to synchronize (to whatever degree) *your* repository with some other Git and its other repository, your Git and their Git have an exchange of IDs—specifically, hash IDs.  Exactly which IDs depends on the direction of the transfer, and any branch *names* you ask your Git to use.
- A *remote-tracking branch* is actually an entity that *your* Git stores, associated with *your* repository.  Your remote-tracking branch `origin/master` is, in effect, your Git's place to remember "what the Git at `origin` said *his* `master` was, the last time we talked."

So, now we take these seven items, and look at how `git fetch` works.  You might run `git fetch origin`, for instance.  At this point, your Git calls up the Git on `origin` and asks it about its branches.  They say things like `master = 1234567` and `branch = 89abcde` (though the hash values are all exactly 40 characters long, rather than these 7-character ones).

Your Git may already have these commit objects.  If so, we are nearly done!  If not, it asks their Git to send those commit objects, and also any additional objects your Git needs to make sense of them.  The additional objects are any files that go with those commits, and any parent commit(s) those commits use that you do not already have, plus the parents' parents, and so on, until we get to some commit object(s) that you *do* have.  This gets you all the commits and files you need for any and all new history.<sup>1</sup>

Once your Git has all the objects safely stored away, your Git then updates your remote-tracking branches with the new IDs.  Their Git just told you that their `master` is `1234567`, so now your `origin/master` is set to `1234567`.  The same goes for their `branch`: it becomes your `origin/branch` and your Git saves the `89abcde` hash.

If you now `git checkout branch`, your Git uses `origin/branch` to make a new local label, pointing to `89abcde`.  Let's draw this:

```
...--o--*--o--1   <-- master, origin/master
         \
          o--8    <-- branch, origin/branch
```

(I've shortened `1234567` to just `1` here, and `89abcde` to just `8`, to get them to fit better.)

To make things really interesting, let's make our *own* new commit on `branch`, too.  Let's say it gets numbered `aaaaaaa...`:

```
...--o--*--o--1    <-- master, origin/master
         \
          o--8     <-- origin/branch
              \
               A   <-- branch
```

(I shortened `aaaaaaa...` to just `A`).

The interesting question, then, is what happens if they—the Git from which *you* fetch—rebase something.  Suppose, for instance, that they rebase `branch` onto `master`.  This copies some number of commits.  Now you run `git fetch` and your Git sees that they say `branch = fedcba9`.  Your Git checks to see if you have this object; if not, you get it (and its files) and its parent (and that commit's files) and so on until we reach some common point—which will, in fact, be commit `1234567`.

Now *you* have this:

```
...--o--*--o--1        <-- master, origin/master
         \     \
          \     o--F   <-- origin/branch
           \
            o--8--A    <-- branch
```

Here I've written `F` for commit `fedcba9`, the one `origin/branch` now points-to.

If you come across this later without realizing that the upstream guys rebased their `branch` (your `origin/branch`), you might look at this and think that *you* must have written *all three* commits in the `o--8--A` chain, because they're on your `branch` and not on `origin/branch` anymore.  But the *reason* they're not on `origin/branch` is that the upstream abandoned them in favor of the new copies.  It's a bit hard to tell that those new copies are, in fact, copies, and that you, too, should abandon those commits.

---

<sup>1</sup>If branches grow in the "normal", "expected" way, it's really easy for your Git and their Git to figure out which commits your Git needs from them: your `origin/master` tells you where you saw their `master` last time, and now their `master` points further down a longer chain.  The commits you need are precisely those on *their* `master` that come after the tip of *your* `origin/master`.

If branches are shuffled around in less-typical ways, it's somewhat harder.  In the most general case, they simply have to enumerate *all* their objects by hash IDs, until your Git tells them that they have reached one you already have.  The specific details get further complicated by shallow clones.

---

#### It's not impossible

It's not *impossible* to tell, and since Git version 2.0 or so, there are now built-in tools to let Git figure it out for you.  (Specifically, `git merge-base --fork-point`, which is invoked by `git rebase --fork-point`, uses your reflog for `origin/branch` to figure out that the `o--8` chain used to be on `origin/branch` at one point.  This only works for the time-period that those reflog entries are retained, but this defaults to at least 30 days, giving you a month to catch up.  That's 30 days in *your* time-line: 30 days from the time *you* run `git fetch`, regardless of how long ago the upstream did the rebase.)

What this really boils down to is that if you and your upstream agree, in advance, that some particular set of branch(es) get rebased, you can arrange to do whatever is required in *your* repository every time they do this.  With a more typical development process, though, you won't expect them to rebase, and if they don't—if they never "abandon" a published commit that you have fetched—then there's nothing you need to recover *from*.

Comment: Professionally explained, thank you for the correct representation.

Answer (score 2):

The main problem with rebasing (or rewriting the history) of the published (remote) branches is that it becomes difficult to reintegrate work based on them. So if those remotes are fetched for review only and no commit, even a merge one, is ever made on top of those you won't generally have many issues. Otherwise merging and resolving conflicts might soon become major annoyance.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer to your question is….

As long as no other users are ever making changes (no new commits on the branch from another developer) to the remote public “collaboration” branches that those single developers are rebasing, then your guests that pull down those branches to their local repositories should not have any issues and see the same clean rebased code. No additional merge commits should occur.

I recommend you tell your developers always pull down latest updates to the master repo first and BEFORE they rebase and push code up to the remote repository. When they get the latest master changes before rebasing they wont end up building more merges or get errors when pushing rebased branches.

Problems arise on rebasing when two or more developers have changed the same branch with new commits while another developer has pushed a rebase without those changes added. When that happens, all developers who pull down the repo and their remote branch will now have duplicate branches coming off different commit “heads” in the master repo followed by a nasty merge commit trying to join every identical copy of their working branch following by a merge to resolve them together. The rebased branch will have to merge with their local branch. It will work, and without conflicts, but the Git history is pretty nasty as it doubles the commits on each branch (the rebased and non-rebased versions coming off master still exist) and makes managing what was once a single branch history very convoluted now.

But what you describe with read-only guests viewing branches is fine.