# How can I do Squashing in git

Tags: eclipse, git

I have made lot of commits for the same project. I got a comment from the customer to squash the commits.
 how can I do the squash through eclipse?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to squash commits in git after they have been pushed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5667884/how-to-squash-commits-in-git-after-they-have-been-pushed)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if or how you can do this from inside Eclipse.

From the commandline you can squash commits using interactive rebase.

```
git rebase -i <earlier commit>
```

This will open your editor. Change the commits you want to squash so that they say `squash` instead of `pick`. An example, squashing `753cafe Second commit` and `cddb7ca Third commit` into `120c1b3 First commit`:

```
pick 120c1b3 First commit
squash 753cafe Second commit
squash cddb7ca Third commit
```

Save and close.

This modifies history. If you have already pushed this somewhere and you need to replace that with the new history, will need to use force push. If others are working on or have based work off of your branch, this will affect them.

More info:

- [Pro Git - Rewriting History](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History)
- [man git-rebase](https://gitirc.eu/git-rebase.html)
- [man git-push](https://gitirc.eu/git-push.html)

Comment: The above mentioned process will work for already pushed commits right?

Comment: Yes. But since you are altering history, you will need to force push, to overwrite the history on your remote.

Comment: @user9469186 While it is possible with a "force push", it's best not to do this unless your certain that other developers have not pulled this branch - it will cause issues when merging their changes as well