# How to squash 7 pushed commits into one in to 1 in git?

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-squash

I have tried multiple ways to squash my remote repo commits but didnt get it right. I want to squash them all and make it one . Below is the list of commits. Below is the summary of my pull request to upstream (which lists 7 commits). I want to list only one instead of 7.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to squash commits in git after they have been pushed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5667884/how-to-squash-commits-in-git-after-they-have-been-pushed)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

```
git reset --soft HEAD~7
git add --all
git commit
git push --force
```

First, reset git index to before the commits you want to squash. Use `--soft` so that git only resets the index and doesn't touch your working directory. Then create a commit as usual.

Answer (score 18):

Another way is to use `squash` - i other work `interactive rebase`

In order to do a git squash follow those steps:

```
# X is the number of commits you wish to squash, in your case 7
# In this interactive rebase there can be more that 7 commits if
# there was a merge in one of them
git rebase -i HEAD~X
```

Once you squash your commits - choose the `s` for squash = it will combine all the commits into a single commit.

[image]

Comment: Your answer is also correct. But I already had got a right answer. And there is no option to tick both the answers "Right". :)