# How should I properly squash previously pushed commits on master?

Tags: git

I'm on the `master` branch and in hindsight, I have pushed too many commit messages (or at least my teammates tell me so). Here's what the log looks like:

```
% git log --oneline
fc71bc8 (HEAD -> mainline, origin/master, origin/HEAD) Renamed 'week' to 'period'
3858ca5 Reverted days in year back to 365
a5d19bb Reverted days in year back to 365
635a4fe Submitting revision 2
edb25c7 Removed var_int as it is no longer needed
af1c576 Added unit tests and addressed comments
72b95a1 Built infrastructure for modeling
d31b45a added augmented model
```

I want to squash commits `3858ca5`, `a5d19bb`, `635a4fe`, `edb25c7`, and `af1c576`. That would leave only commits `fc71bc8`, `72b95a1`, and `d31b45a`. Of course, I want to retain the code changes in the squashed commits, I just want them to be wrapped into commit `72b95a1`. How can I best do this?

I want to reiterate that these commits have already been pushed to `master` on the remote repository. I'm not solely talking about commits on my local computer as was done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6934752/combining-multiple-commits-before-pushing-in-git).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+squash+multiple+commits

Comment: More appropriate duplicate: [How to squash commits in git after they have been pushed?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5667884/2745495)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is normally done with rebase -i:

```
git rebase -i d31b45a
# first revision will be 72b95a1, with pick, leave it like that
# the following IDs for the revisions you want to squash, set them to squash
# leave the one for fc71bc8 in pick
# save and exit
# rebase will start running and will open on the editor so you set the message
# for all those squashed commits
# set the message, save  and exit and rebase should finish
# and the squashed revisions should be there
```

Comment: This would work for code that hasn't already been pushed. What if I need to do this for code that is already pushed to the master? Would this override previous pushes? I modified my question to emphasize the fact that the code is already pushed.