# [Git]: fatal: invalid upstream 'origin/master~2'

Tags: git, git-rebase

I am trying to do a [rebase on the remote branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5668050/10515002), but I get the following error:

```bash
$ git rebase -i origin/master~2 master
# fatal: invalid upstream 'origin/master~2'
```

I have tried to do a `git fetch` and `git pull` but it doesn't fix the problem.

In the `git log` I can see the following:

```bash
$ git log
# commit 611e384e89da3cec1e45bf59d7564580912e5073 (HEAD -> master, origin/master)
# Author: Shahrad Elahi <shahradq@gmail.com>                                     
# Date:   Sun Oct 30 14:38:57 2022 +0330                                         
#                                                                                
#     Initial Commit                                                             
#                                                                                
# commit 8ae591b238960b862eb67bbb37377b5ca1611c47                                
# Author: Shahrad Elahi <shahradq@gmail.com>                                     
# Date:   Sun Oct 30 14:34:50 2022 +0330                                         
#                                                                                
#     Initial Commit
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only have 2 commits, you cannot rebase onto the third-last. origin/master is 611e38; origin/master~1 is 8ae591; origin/master~2 does not exist. If you want to rebase all commits, including the root commit, use `git rebase -i --root`.

Answer (score 1):

That's not gonna fly because `origin/master~2` does not exist. Try `git rebase -i --root master`

Comment: Knittl beat me to it (writing on the cellphone can be tricky :-)).